# Combining and reshape-ing ndarray so that original values of each component are on the first axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

For [numpy stacks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and [linear algebra](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html), you want to format data with the stacks on the first-axis.

For example, to use the [determinant](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html#numpy.linalg.det), the parameter needs to be an array-like where the last two axes are symmetric, e.g. (x,M,M)

How can I reformat four separate flattened arrays (corresponding to the coefficients of a 2x2 matrix) into such a format?

I've been tinkering around with https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block, and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html,

but so far haven't gotten it into the format I think I need.

For example, I get very close with

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
c = np.array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
d = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
result = np.dstack((a, b, c, d))
result = np.reshape(result, (1, 5, 2, 2))
print("RESULT SHAPE", result.shape)
print("RESULT VALUE", result[:, :, 0, 0])
print("RESULT I REALLY WANT", result[:, 0, 0])
```

Not sure how to drop the last axis.

Comment: Wait, I feel dumb now. I think I can do:

`new_result = np.reshape(result, (-1, 2, 2))`

Is there a simpler way than doing this sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [250]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
     ...: b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]) 
     ...: c = np.array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19]) 
     ...: d = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
```

`np.stack` is a version of `concatenate` that joins the arrays on a new axis - which we can choose:

```
In [251]: np.stack((a,b,c,d)).shape                                             
Out[251]: (4, 5)
In [252]: np.stack((a,b,c,d),1).shape                                           
Out[252]: (5, 4)
```

We can then reshape the last axis to (2,2):

```
In [253]: np.stack((a,b,c,d),1).reshape(5,2,2)                                  
Out[253]: 
array([[[  1,  10],
        [ 15, 100]],

       [[  2,  20],
        [ 16, 200]],

       [[  3,  30],
        [ 17, 300]],

       [[  4,  40],
        [ 18, 400]],

       [[  5,  50],
        [ 19, 500]]])
```

The first stack is the same as `np.array`:

```
In [254]: np.array((a,b,c,d)).shape                                             
Out[254]: (4, 5)
In [255]: np.array((a,b,c,d)).reshape(2,2,5)                                    
Out[255]: 
array([[[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
        [ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50]],

       [[ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
        [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]])
```

now use `transpose` to move that 5 batch dimension to the start:

```
In [256]: np.array((a,b,c,d)).reshape(2,2,5).transpose(2,0,1)
```

So there are various ways of joining the arrays, and fiddling with the dimensions.  I don't think any one is inherently simpler.  `reshape` and `transpose` are cheap, so use them freely.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up and the solution you found.

I realize that `np.stack((a,b,c,d),1)` is functionally equivalent to the `np.dstack((a, b, c, d))` I had above after doing the re-shape.